# Can you question an already issued patent

Tags: support

First off, great and inspiring site!

I've read a lot of topics on submitting prior art for patent *applications*. Does the same rules apply for already issued patents? I could just save the prior art and wait for the lawsuit, but i'd rather take a proactive stand :)

//R

Comment: See [If a patent has been issued, can it still be invalidated by prior art?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/587), [What is the time period allowed to get a “post-grant review”?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/528)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, part of the patent process is the ability to challenge existing patents. From the [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Ask Patents - Stack Exchange is a collaboratively edited Q&A platform for patent experts, inventors and citizens who wish to participate in the US patent process. Its primary purpose is to help individuals:
>
> **1. Solicit help finding prior art that might apply *to a patent* or application**
> 2. Get answers to hard questions about specific patents
> 3. Ask questions about the US patent system or process

*(emphasis mine)*